# jqGrid checkAll not working inside of If/else block?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

This is the code in the grid. This is just to test some functionality so I can code something similar elsewhere. There are two columns with checkboxes; however, it will only check all the boxes in one of those columns. It is supposed to check all checkboxes in both columns the first time it loads.

The weird thing is, if I take `$elem.multiselect("checkAll");` out of the if/else, it will check the boxes in both columns.

```
var checkFirstLoad = getObjectFromLocalStorage('CheckAllCheck');
                if (checkFirstLoad == "No") {
                    //do nothing
                } else {
                    $elem.multiselect("checkAll");
                }
                saveObjectInLocalStorage('CheckAllCheck', 'No');
```

Here is the code on the webpage to remove the local object so I can test the code:

```
<input type="button" id="removeItemButton" value="Remove Local Item" onclick="removeObjectFromLocalStorage('CheckAllCheck')" />
<script>
        removeObjectFromLocalStorage = function (storageItemName) {
            if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
                window.localStorage.removeItem(storageItemName);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Any ideas? I'm a little lost.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear where `getObjectFromLocalStorage()` is defined in your code. It is also not clear how to test this code. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You may also want to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Where is the code related to jqGrid? Please provide a run able code example.